# Get closest address from coordinates using OSM Nominatim

Tags: openstreetmap, reverse-geocoding, nominatim

I am trying to do a reverse lookup to get the closest address to a set of coordinates using OSM Nominatim. I keep getting a `way` instead of a `node` though, which doesn't include a house number. Is there a way to force it to give the nearest `node`?

For example: https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=jsonv2&lat=51.989911&lon=4.219650

I am pretty new to Nominatim, so sorry if this is a stupid question :)

Comment: What exactly is your problem here? Did you run Nominatim?

Comment: I'm not running Nominatim myself, I'm using the service from nominatim.openstreetmap.org. The problem is that I want to find the nearest address to a location, but I'm not always getting a full address. In the example I gave I'm not getting a house number.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so whats happening is that you're not close to a building. It therefore shows you a  cycleway and not a `house_number`

https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=jsonv2&lat=51.990819&lon=4.220295

Is near where you want to be, and it does show you a house number because you are on a building.

Would you expect a field of cows to have a house numbers for example?

Comment: Thanks, but I want to get the closest full address. The coordinates will be input by users, so I have no control over that.If it's a field of cows I still want to closest address, even if that's 10 kilometers away.

Comment: Youre better off implementing Notanim yourself then, this is the implementation they picked for you. There are more powerful alternatives, such as Azure reverse geocoding